# How can I fix the error "Access Denied" in WSL?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to set up Windows Subsystem for Linux on my Surface Laptop running Windows 10 Version 1909 (Build 18363.836). I am encountering an issue when attempting to create a user account. I have tried multiple distros such as Kali Linux, Ubuntu, and Debian. Here is what I get on every distro:

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
Access is denied.
Please create a default UNIX user account. The username does not need to match your Windows username.
For more information visit: https://aka.ms/wslusers
Enter new UNIX username:
```

When I create a user account, I get the error Access Denied:

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
Access is denied.
Please create a default UNIX user account. The username does not need to match your Windows username.
For more information visit: https://aka.ms/wslusers
Enter new UNIX username: test
Access is denied.
Enter new UNIX username:
```

This goes on in an infinite loop. I have tried the following:

- Reinstalling the distro from the Microsoft Store.
- Resetting the app from Windows Settings.
- Repairing the app from Windows Settings.
- Turning of Windows Defender Application Control in Group Policy Editor.
- Installing a different distro.

I have also noticed that when I open PowerShell, CMD, or Windows Terminal and I type `bash`, I get access denied. I have also tried running bash as an administrator from Run, File Explorer, and from Windows Search. I have made sure that I have permission to execute `bash.exe`. I have also tried making myself the owner of `bash.exe`.

Does anyone know what's going on? Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Here is the screenshot requested by Ramhound.
[image]

**EDIT:**

I was referring to [this post](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3352) which described another way to restart the LxssManager.

I ran into an error while doing this. I see that I do not have permission to restart the service properly.

Here is the output of `sc stop LxssManager` which was used in order to try and restart LxssManager. (This was done in an elevated command prompt.)

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc stop LxssManager                                                                                                                                                                                                         

SERVICE_NAME: LxssManager                                                                                                       

TYPE               : 30  WIN32                                                                                          

STATE              : 3  STOP_PENDING                                                                                                            

(NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)                                                 

WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)                                                                                           

SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)                                                                                           

CHECKPOINT         : 0x2                                                                                                

WAIT_HINT          : 0xea60
```

Here is the output when done in a regular Command Prompt (not elevated).

```
C:\Users\aadit>sc stop LxssManager
[SC] OpenService FAILED 5:

Access is denied.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108595/discussion-on-question-by-todd-how-can-i-fix-the-error-access-denied-in-wsl).